# Dit-on plutôt Il n’a pas réussi à son examen ce matin ou Il n’a pas réussi son examen ce matin?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation-idiomatique

Il n’a pas réussi à son examen ce matin.

Il n’a pas réussi son examen ce matin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ne peut pas dire *<s>Il a raté à son examen</s>* mais avec réussir, les formes avec et sans la préposition *à* sont possibles. La deuxième, *il a réussi son examen*, est plus courante.

Dans *réussir son examen*, on a affaire à un complément d'objet direct. C'est l'examen qui est réussi alors que dans *réussir à son examen*, il s'agit d'un complément circonstanciel.